# If a $var1 equals a string then set $var2 equal to another string

Tags: php, if-statement

Basically if $var1 = 'Refi' then I want $var2 = 'Refinance'. If $var = 'Purch' or 'Purchase' then I need $var2 = 'Purchase'.

```
$var2 = '';

if (!(strcasecmp($var1, 'Refi') === false)) {
$var2 = 'Refinance';
}

if (!(strcasecmp($var1, 'Purch') === false) || !(strcasecmp($var1, 'Purchase') === false)) {
$var2 = 'Purchase';
}
```

The output I am getting is just defaulting to 'Purchase'. I also need the strings to be case insensitive. I don't know what is going on with it, the logic seems correct in my help.

Comment: [strcasecmp](http://docs.php.net/strcasecmp) returns an integer. So it's never === (type-safe equal) false.

Comment: But could be `== false`, if evaluated to 0 (which would be equally wrong, since `0` means strings are equal, thus should be `true`)

Answer (score 2):

strcasecmp does not return a bool. It returns an int.

```
$var2 = '';

if ((strcasecmp($var1, 'Refi') == 0)) { 
  $var2 = 'Refinance';
}

if ((strcasecmp($var1, 'Purch') == 0) || (strcasecmp($var1, 'Purchase') == 0)) {
  $var2 = 'Purchase';
}
```

Check out documentation for details. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php